# Why aren't there any SF “anywhere remote” jobs?

Tags: discussion

I see many places needing SF Admins and developers but no one seems to be looking for remote admins or developers despite SF is in the cloud. I am not referring to the site where one bids for a job but rather regular employment.

Basically anyone not living somewhere in the U.S., U.K. (even if they are legally able to work there) is very limited.

Any good reason for it?

Are there any relatively unknown sites that have such positions that don't show in Google? Or know of consultancies that accept U.S. citizens abroad?

Comment: Companies in SF are often willing to look for such workers because the cost is so exorbitant there, and the workforce is unstable, often jumping quite quickly from job to job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BY/UA here.
I believe that it's kind of stereotype - US companies want worker on-site. Full stop.
You can find remote work only on freelance sites. You can find full-time there, however it's not common.
The same problem here. I don't want to work in office in Minsk and I'm not wiling to relocate anywhere. You can try to search interesting application in AppExchange and write to that company if they need a remote admin/dev. It's just a luck to find a company which don't care where you are, they just need cheaper admin/dev then in US/UK (my $35 vs their more than $70).

> Any good reason for it?

Just stereotype, I think, or corporate policies. I've been working remotely for 3 years and there is no problem to talk via Skype/other video app.

> Are there any relatively unknown sites that have such positions that don't show in Google? Or know of consultancies that accept U.S. citizens abroad?

I don't believe so. Famous job sites for US have remote jobs from time to time. Stackexchange has remote jobs from time to time.

Comment: How did you find your remote job?

Comment: :-) It was office first time. After a half a year there was no comrades in the office, so there was no reason to come there, however, I worked in office with other guys from my company. Then, I decided to move to Minsk and my company let me work in 'home office'. Another client with whom I will work full time was found in upwork. I did a small project and now will work for some time as full time remote developer.

Answer (score 10):

Remote jobs are much more common than you may think. A lot of it depends on your experience level and the type of job itself. Remote developer positions are much more common than remote admin positions for very good reasons. Admin roles tend to require user interaction and training of users. How can you do "admin by walking around" if you're not on site? Ditto for helping with user adoption? So when it comes to admin work, it greatly depends on the maturity of the org and what they want done.

As a developer, I've worked with clients all over the country. I've also interviewed for a number of permanent or long-term 1099 positions. I found some of those through word of mouth while many others were advertised in the Success Community in the [Job Postings Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001oZT) owned by @DanielHoechst which I help moderate. There's another fairly new Group on Success Community called Remote Jobs along with the SFDC Developers Group where remote jobs will be listed. You'll find positions advertised in the [Developer Forum's Job Board](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Jobs_Board&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS).

Sites I'm aware of outside the Salesforce ecosystem include [CrmMarket](https://www.crmmarket.com/jobs/), [Virtual Vocations](https://www.virtualvocations.com/jobs), the [Hired on Demand Jobs Board](http://jobboard.hireon-demand.com/JobSeeker/Jobs.aspx?abbr=HIREOD) and [Guru](http://www.guru.com/d/jobs/q/salesforce-development/), the latter of which is mostly for freelancers. Be aware that the fact you're located outside the US, even if you're legally able to work in the US, could easily be an issue for some who might otherwise hire you remotely. Most, will want you to be available during the hours they're working, not just during the work hours for your time zone. That's a big issue in that they want it to be convenient for *them*.

With some companies who use remote developers, they will have them come at least once/month to their location for face to face team meetings. Proficiency in English is also very important to them as is communication in general. Having a good reputation on sites like this or the Developer Community is always very helpful.

Comment: This was helpful.

Comment: Glad you think so. BTW, I just interviewed for one yesterday. ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are companies that use a similar model to this with remote workers, such as Appirio using their [topcoder](http://crowdsourcing.topcoder.com/) site to crowdsource software and there are other sites like [Freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com) where companies may post projects. Many of these are quite small scale projects so would be quite tricky to earn a living from but it is possible.

The larger job sites do have these sorts of roles from time to time as Andrew has already noted.